# Android: I am getting white screen in webview instead of web page

Tags: android, android-webview, parameters

I am trying to load ccavenue page inside my android app in webview, but instead of ccavenue webpage I am getting blank screen. I am clueless why it is happening when I am passing everything correctly.
Please check my code and let me know where I am doing wrong.

```
StringBuffer params = new StringBuffer();
            params.append(ServiceUtility.addToPostParams(AvenuesParams.ACCESS_CODE,mainIntent.getStringExtra(AvenuesParams.ACCESS_CODE)));
            params.append(ServiceUtility.addToPostParams(AvenuesParams.MERCHANT_ID,mainIntent.getStringExtra(AvenuesParams.MERCHANT_ID)));
            params.append(ServiceUtility.addToPostParams(AvenuesParams.ORDER_ID,mainIntent.getStringExtra(AvenuesParams.ORDER_ID)));
            params.append(ServiceUtility.addToPostParams(AvenuesParams.REDIRECT_URL,mainIntent.getStringExtra(AvenuesParams.REDIRECT_URL)));
            params.append(ServiceUtility.addToPostParams(AvenuesParams.CANCEL_URL,mainIntent.getStringExtra(AvenuesParams.CANCEL_URL)));
            params.append(ServiceUtility.addToPostParams(AvenuesParams.ENC_VAL, encVal));

            String vPostParams = params.substring(0, params.length() - 1);

            try {
                String postData = URLEncoder.encode(vPostParams, "UTF-8");
                webview.postUrl(Constants.TRANS_URL, postData.getBytes());
                Log.d("webview test", "testing");
                Log.d("webview test",vPostParams);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                showToast("Exception occured while opening webview.");
            }
```

Value of string vPostParams is,

```
access_code=AVBJ63DA70BU19JBUB&merchant_id=86529&order_id=2383911&redirect_url=http://52.11.225.96&cancel_url=http://52.11.225.96&enc_val=FE9+b0quu5a8GBqGPG0yGA6bnqJLi34iW2hdxwKTo0sPfZRJDQwQxOzCAoN06CYB1n+gUQz5knNNfNcD5IBcbRs5aJtMs0pc9Beekj5lk9bFMd8BGgUse9oHeKqhOQc5WBLDOETAO/Hu9YNS4MTHNweieCP10PHj9eMzDEOgzjkbNwc8vhU4arYvSjwqT3JKtQKpVlwWL47StVNB/6SsVutmyudbesNGx626ZK9VbcTrpqabFWHQ2p2aQH9tW5YcApbUnLChbfmEyCTZ7YyO0jafQcbDWsRa4XT8XTXGY4KvZBn1VkeYBSJ91zIjT2yR+XMgahbrGVtUcOK8midvJA==
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` in your app's build.gradle 
and add this code

```
        StringBuffer params = new StringBuffer();
        params.append(ServiceUtility.addToPostParams(AvenuesParams.ACCESS_CODE,mainIntent.getStringExtra(AvenuesParams.ACCESS_CODE)));
        params.append(ServiceUtility.addToPostParams(AvenuesParams.MERCHANT_ID,mainIntent.getStringExtra(AvenuesParams.MERCHANT_ID)));
        params.append(ServiceUtility.addToPostParams(AvenuesParams.ORDER_ID,mainIntent.getStringExtra(AvenuesParams.ORDER_ID)));
        params.append(ServiceUtility.addToPostParams(AvenuesParams.REDIRECT_URL,mainIntent.getStringExtra(AvenuesParams.REDIRECT_URL)));
        params.append(ServiceUtility.addToPostParams(AvenuesParams.CANCEL_URL,mainIntent.getStringExtra(AvenuesParams.CANCEL_URL)));
        params.append(ServiceUtility.addToPostParams(AvenuesParams.ENC_VAL, URLEncoder.encode(encVal)));

        String vPostParams = params.substring(0, params.length() - 1);

        try {
            String postData = URLEncoder.encode(vPostParams, "UTF-8");
            webview.postUrl(Constants.TRANS_URL, EncodingUtils.getBytes(vPostParams, "UTF-8"));
            Log.d("webview test", "testing");
            Log.d("webview test",postData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showToast("Exception occured while opening webview.");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is work for me check it out.

```
public class CCAvenue extends ActionBarActivity {

WebView webView1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ccavenue);

    webView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    String url = "http://www.example.com/controllers/user/cckit/ccavRequestHandler.php";

    webView1.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

    webView1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    webView1.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
    webView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            /* This call inject JavaScript into the page which just finished loading. */
            webView1.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
        }

    });

    String postData = "merchant_id=12345&order_id=12345678912&amount=1&currency=INR" +
            "&cancel_url=http://www.example.com/" +
            "&redirect_url=http://www.example.com/controllers/user/cckit/ccavResponseHandler.php" +
            "&language=EN";


    webView1.postUrl(url,EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
    //webView1.loadUrl(url);
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         view.loadUrl(url);
         return true;
      }
   }

class MyJavaScriptInterface
{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void processHTML(String html)
    {
       // here you can handel response from CCAvenue.
       System.out.println("Response : " + html);
    }
}
```